# Raised segments in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, semantic-ui

I come from `Semantic-UI` and I'm learning `Bootstrap`. Despite Bootstrap being the more popular framework by far, I'm finding it a bit underwhelming, lacking some basic stylings that come out-of-the-box with Semantic-UI.

At the moment, I'm searching for the equivalent of Semantic-UI's "raised segments", basically bordered containers with shadows that make them look "raised" above the other content, like you can see here:

https://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#raised

Is there anything similar in Bootstrap, or do I have to roll my own, using CSS `border`s and `box-shadow`s? (I know it's relatively easy to do in CSS, but I just want to be sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Bootstrap doesn't have a build in style for shadow, you will need to declare your own default easily using the following:

```
.box-shadow-strength-0{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px 0px black;
}

.box-shadow-strength-1{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px 5px black;
}

.box-shadow-strength-2{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px 10px black;
}
....
```

Here is what each of the value does:

```
box-shadow: [horizontal] [vertical] [blur] [spread] [color];
```

You can read more about CSS **box-shadow** and browsers support here:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

You can also use generator online to try out different possibilities using the following tool:
https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer